# javamail works from desktop but not android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, jakarta-mail

i have a javamail based gmail program, i tried using a standalone java app on the desktop and had no trouble, but when i run on android emulator i am getting:

D/SntpClient(   74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol

CODE:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com"); 
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth", "true"); 
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.debug", "true"); 
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        try {
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
          Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
          store.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, "xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxx");
```

Comment: does not appear  to work from device either

Comment: also, this seems to be Service problem, works fine from activity but not from service. any ideas on why this might be?